# Creating a page transition where it fades to white, but this does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("Natwest").css("display", "none");
            $("Natwest").fadeIn(2000);
    });
</script>
```

Are there any errors with this? I'm creating a page transition where it fades to white, but the code I have written doesn't seem to work.

Natwest is a css class.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this code? Are there any js errors?

Comment: what is `Natwest` ? if its a id use id selector `$("#Natwest")` and if its a css class then use `$('.Natwest')`, moreover you can simply use `.hide()` function to make an element disappear ...

Comment: Also, you might as well add `display:none` to the css of "Natwest" so it loads hidden.  No reason to do it in code on page load.

Answer (score 1):

I think

`$("Natwest")` should be `$("#Natwest")` or `$(".Natwest")`.

So if `Natwest` is `ID` then `#Natwest` of if `class` then `.Natwest`.

**BUT**

what you're trying is like `<Natwest>` which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use id selectors with `#`:

```
$("#Natwest").css("display", "none");
$("#Natwest").fadeIn(2000);
// if your element looks like this: <div id="Natwest"></div>"
```

$("Natwest") looks for all `<Natwest>` tags on the page - there probably aren't any since it's not a standard tag.

`#` selects an [element by id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). `.` selects an element by [its class name](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `$("Natwest")` if its Natwest is a class you use `$(".Natwest")` or if its an ID you use `$("#Natwest")`